# textbox and select box combining value in a single text(1st tb value,then sb value)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show textbox and select box combining value in a single text(1st tb value,then sb value).
 This is the jsp page:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>A : </td>
<td><input type="text" id="text1" name="customer" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>B :</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" onclick="change(this, 'select1000')" name="license[1]" value="1000"> 25-1000</td>
<td><div id="select1000" style="display: none">
<select id="select" name="selectbox">    
<option test="l25" value="25">25</option>
<option test="l100" value="100">100</option>
<option test="l175" value="175">175</option>
<option test="l250" value="250">250</option>
<option test="l325" value="325">325</option>
</select>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td> ShowValue: </td>
<td><input type="text" name="key" id="text2" value="" disabled="disabled"></td> </tr>
</table>
```

I want to show the both textbox A and selectbox value B in ShowValuetextbox(1st textbx value come then selectbox),for this I have written the jquery :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#text1").keyup(function() {
$("#text2").val($("#text1").val() + $(this).find('option:selected').val()).change();
});

$("#select").keyup(function(){
$("#text2").val($("#text1").val() + $(this).find('option:selected').val()).change();
});
</script>
```

not getting the expected output,any inputs guys........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all of you for sharing your inputs but I have written this(though showing a comment in the textbox2)but This is working for me :

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#text1").keyup(function(){
//   $("#text2").val($("#text1").val());
   $("#text2").val($("#text1").val() + $(this).find('option:selected').val()).change();
  });
});

     $(document).ready(function(){
  $('select[name="selectbox"]').change(function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    $('input[name="key"]').val(selectedValue);
    $("#text2").val($("#text1").val() + $(this).find('option:selected').val()).change();
  });

});
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dude : In the code there is a small mistake. Replace it with this .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#text1").keyup(function() {
$("#text2").val($("#text1").val() + $("#select").find('option:selected').val()).change();
});

$("#select").change(function(){
$("#text2").val($("#text1").val() + $(this).find('option:selected').val()).change();
});
</script>
```

Is there any special reason you call .change() event for text 2 ?? 
Also You can get the selected value of the dropdown using simply $("#select").val();

Comment: @Vivekanand -  Yup it will but using find unnecessarily is not required and its a bit of a performance hit when there are huge number of options available. So its better used .val(). Also accept the appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){    

        $('#text1').keyup(function() {
             $('#text2').val($(this).val()+$('#select').val());
        });


    });
</script>
```

This works for me i tried to put it in jsfiddle but its down for me.
also you should use document.ready to ensure events properly bind

Answer (score 1):

```
var sel = $("#select"),
    txt_1 = $("#text1"),
    txt_2 = $("#text2");

txt_1.on('keyup', function() {
    txt_2.val( $.trim( this.value ) + sel.val() );
});

sel.on('change', function() {
    txt_2.val( $.trim( txt_1.val() ) + this.value );
});
```